# How to detect the physical snapshot button in a USB webcam using C#?

Tags: c#, button, webcam, dllimport, snapshot

I want to detect in my C# code whenever the user presses the physical snapshot button in a webcam.

I discovered that the webcam's own software application has a dll (`emDLL.dll`) that contains various functions, and I used Dependency Walker to know if it includes an exported function that does what I want. And yes, it has one, whose unmangled name is `int IsButtonPressed(void)`

Reviewing various responses referred to this issue, I managed myself to write the C# code below to test that unmanaged DLL's function:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class PlatformInvokeTest3
{
    // EntryPoint is assigned with the mangled name of the exported unmangled function int CEM2800Prop::IsButtonPressed(void)
    [DllImport(@"emDLL.dll", EntryPoint = "?IsButtonPressed@CEM2800Prop@@QAEHXZ")]

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public static extern int IsButtonPressed();

    public static void Main()
    {
       int Aux;
       Aux = IsButtonPressed();

    }
}
```

The problem is that when the code reaches the point when the function is called, appears an exception with the following error:

```
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
```

I need to know what is wrong in my code and if there are some way to call from within my C# code that emDLL.dll function.

Thanks to all.